# Need to ignore case in preg_match_all usage

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, web-scraping, preg-match-all

Im trying to crape html and grab items between `<tr>` tags.  Some of the tags are coming through as uppercase for some reason ( `<TR>` ) and are being ignored by my pattern.  How can i tell my pattern to ignore case.

My current pattern is:

```
preg_match_all("|<tr(.*)</tr>|U",$table,$rows);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`i` modifier<sup>DOCS</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
preg_match("|<tr(.*></tr>|Ui", ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `i` flag at the end of you regex:

```
preg_match_all("|<tr(.*)</tr>|Ui",$table,$rows);
```

However you should avoid to combine regex with HTML.